# Building OpenCV 4 requires CC 5.3 or higher - RTX 2080TI

Tags: opencv, cudnn

I am trying to build the OpenCV 4.2.0 with `OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON` in Ubuntu 18.04, but I get the below CMake error even though I have a NVIDIA 2080TI GPU which has a [CC 7.5](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

> CUDA backend for DNN module requires CC 5.3 or higher.  Please remove
>     unsupported architectures from CUDA_ARCH_BIN option.

Edit: The value of `CUDA_ARCH_BIN` is `3.0 3.5 3.7 5.0 5.2 6.0 6.1 7.0 7.5`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my build options

```
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules/ \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
```

This is the full CMake output

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected processor: x86_64
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.17") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.9", minimum required is "3.2") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable exact version "3.6.9") 
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFAST_MATH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFAST_MATH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFAST_MATH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFAST_MATH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_ssse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse41.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_popcnt.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse42.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512common.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512skx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so  
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.9") 
-- Found WebP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so  
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ABSOLUTE_VALUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ABSOLUTE_VALUE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34") 
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_REORDER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_REORDER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_RESULT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_RESULT - Success
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.22.30
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.56.4
-- IPPICV: Download: ippicv_2019_lnx_intel64_general_20180723.tgz
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/ghost/cv4/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
-- at: /home/ghost/cv4/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDNN: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so (found suitable version "7.6.5", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- CUDA detected: 10.2
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-D_FORCE_INLINES
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for dgemm_
-- Looking for dgemm_ - found
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Looking for cheev_
-- Looking for cheev_ - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Pylint (missing: PYLINT_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Flake8 (missing: FLAKE8_EXECUTABLE) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Looking for dlerror in dl
-- Looking for dlerror in dl - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/ghost/cv4/opencv/build/python_loader
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_ALIASING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_ALIASING - Success
-- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
--   Found libavcodec, version 57.107.100
--   Found libavformat, version 57.83.100
--   Found libavutil, version 55.78.100
--   Found libswscale, version 4.8.100
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-base-1.0, version 1.14.5
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-app-1.0, version 1.14.5
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-riff-1.0, version 1.14.5
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-pbutils-1.0, version 1.14.5
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE - Success
-- Checking for module 'freetype2'
--   Found freetype2, version 21.0.15
-- Checking for module 'harfbuzz'
--   Found harfbuzz, version 1.7.2
-- freetype2:   YES (ver 21.0.15)
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 1.7.2)
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/ghost/cv4/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:99 (message):
  CUDA backend for DNN module requires CC 5.3 or higher.  Please remove
  unsupported architectures from CUDA_ARCH_BIN option.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ghost/cv4/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ghost/cv4/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: did you try "Please remove unsupported architectures from CUDA_ARCH_BIN option."?

Comment: I saw that message on the log but I have no idea on how to do that. Any help is appreciated. (However the problem is opencv not recognizing the correct CC)

Comment: I managed to print the value of `CUDA_ARCH_BIN`. It is `3.0 3.5 3.7 5.0 5.2 6.0 6.1 7.0 7.5`

Comment: And which ones of those are not 5.3 or higher?

Comment: There is a foreach loop in the CMake (opencv/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt line 98)which goes like `foreach(cc ${CC_LIST})
    if(cc VERSION_LESS 5.3)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "...")` This is where it fails

Comment: well, if you need your compiled opencv only for the pc with the 2080 ti in it, just use 7.5, taken from this list: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute. If you want to use all that are supported by opencv, ust, 6.0 6.1 7.0 and 7.5 (>= 5.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled successfully by specifying `CUDA_ARCH_BIN` manually

```
-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=5.3,6.0,6.1,7.0,7.5 -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX=7.5
```

Comment: When I first read this I thought I needed to print CUDA_ARCH_BIN to see what version I had -- this is not necessary just list all of them like he has in the solution (I also did 7.6). The CUDA_ARCH_PTX is printed before the check "Found CUDNN: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/lib/x64/cudnn.lib (found suitable version "7.6.4", minimum required is "7.5")" -- so I put 7.6